# How can I explain to New Zealand that I am not barred re-entry to UK?

Tags: working-visas, us-citizens, new-zealand

2 months ago, I was refused entry at the border due not meeting the General Visitor requirements Section 4.2. I was told I was not banned from re-entry to UK and my refusal letter makes no mention of a re-entry ban. The refusal letter summarises that I am being refused entry because:

[image]

It also states:

[image]

There is no mention of a re-entry ban in the letter as I have seen in other refusal letters.

I have now applied for the New Zealand Working Holiday Visa. I was asked to explain my refusal in the UK which I did by describing what happened and sending a scan of my refusal letter as well as my passport.

They replied asking:

'Please advise if you have been prohibited from re-entering the UK. We would appreciate if you could provide any supporting document confirming that you have not been banned from entering the UK again within 04 August 2017.'

I have already supplied them with the complete refusal letter.

Is there another way I can explain or show that I am not barred re-entry to the UK?

Answer (score 2):

If what you have provided is insufficient to satisfy the authorities in New Zealand, you may wish to make a [Subject Access Request (SAR)](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/580093/SAR_Form_Dec_2016.docx).

> **[Request your personal data from UK Visas and Immigration](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration)**
>
> The Data Protection Act 1998 determines how we process personal data (information relating to living people). The act means you can ask to access the information we hold about you.
>
> These requests are called subject access requests. You should expect a response from us within 40 days.

Comment: Hi Dorothy, 

I am a US Citizen, I live in Dallas, TX. Is this service available to me? 
Is there any other way you can think?

Comment: @CharlieSong yes, it is; it similar to the US Freedom of Information request.